# Replacing contents inside docx and pdf file using asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

In my application I am using some templates in docx and pdf format. I am storing this  docs to DB as Bytes.

Befor showing/sending this docs back to user or application I need to replace some contents inside the doc. eg:if the doc contain @@username@@ I need to replace this with the exact username of the customer. I am not getting a proper solution for this. Any good ideas?

Answer (score 2):

For the docx file, your best bet is to use OpenXML, and instead of having special text like @@username@@, replace it with a content control that you can fill in.

Since you specified docx, you can use OpenXML, which is great, it's an API.  If it has to work with older doc files, then you'll have to automate Word (which should be avoided if at all possible).

For the PDF, your best bet is to create a PDF form, and fill it in a runtime (using a tool like itextsharp).

HTH,
Brian

Answer (score 0):

**For DOC / DOCX:** 
You should use the MSWord object model through MSWord assembly reference (will work only on machines which have msoffice installed.. or else you can use something like [ASPOSE word](http://www.google.co.in/url?q=http://www.aspose.com/categories/.net-components/aspose.words-for-.net/default.aspx&sa=U&ei=d9wATamZGo_qrQeAw_2QDw&ved=0CBoQqwMoBTAA&usg=AFQjCNFLXTkUSyzWXOX49pDsNHBtAaFVqw) libraries which wont need msoffice installation on server). You can programmatically trigger the Find-Replace context of word through the library's API.

**For PDF:** You will need a third party library for editing pdf files.. 3rd party libraries like [ABCpdf](http://www.google.co.in/url?q=http://www.websupergoo.com/abcpdf-1.htm&sa=U&ei=WNwATdmGH4HrrQf1-fmQDw&ved=0CA8QFjAA&usg=AFQjCNHif4Tjsseex4sUCiHVE8Z-4AhbKQ) are available.. (not sure whether Adobe itself has something for this)
The same mechanism like for word library.. but I am not sure whether you will be able to trigger the Find-replace context here or do something else... I have not used a pdf generation library.